# Laravel: GroupBy and orderBy not working together

Tags: laravel, join, group-by, sql-order-by

I'm trying to select all attachments of a person and group by a field but if I add `orderBy` clause to show only last document of that category it doesn't work.
It always use first id to group.

Using `->get()->unique('gruppo_cors')` instead of `groupBy` it works but I have a problem of performance issues because I am in a datatable with much data.

What I'm doing wrong?

```
Allegato::leftjoin('tsys_corsi','tsys_corsi.id_auto','allegati_files.tipo')
        ->orderBy('scadenza','DESC') //in allegati_files table
        ->groupBy('gruppo_cors');//in tsys_corsi table
```

I want to show only most recent document of the group but I always see the first id of allegati_files.

Full query:

```html
$query = Allegato::select('allegati_files.*','allegati_tipologie_new.id_tipologia as id_tipologia',
        'elenco_allegati_tipologie.nome_tipologia','elenco_allegati_tipologie.ordinamento as ordinamento_tipologia',
        'elenco_allegati_tipologie2.id_auto as id_tipologia_grouped',
         'elenco_allegati_categorie.nome_categoria','elenco_allegati_categorie.ordinamento as ordinamento_categoria',
        'elenco_allegati_categorie.shortname_categoria', 'elenco_allegati_categorie.id_auto as id_categoria')
        ->join('allegati_tipologie_new','allegati_tipologie_new.id_allegato','allegati_files.allegato_id')
        ->join('elenco_allegati_tipologie','elenco_allegati_tipologie.id_auto','allegati_tipologie_new.id_tipologia')
        ->join('elenco_allegati_categorie',function($j) use($allowed_cats){
            $j->on('elenco_allegati_categorie.id_auto','elenco_allegati_tipologie.id_categoria');
            $j->whereIn('elenco_allegati_categorie.id_auto',$allowed_cats);
        })
        ->leftjoin('tsys_corsi','tsys_corsi.id_auto','allegati_files.tipo')
        ->leftjoin('elenco_allegati_tipologie as elenco_allegati_tipologie2',function($j){
            $j->on('elenco_allegati_tipologie2.id_auto','allegati_tipologie_new.id_tipologia');
            $j->where('elenco_allegati_tipologie2.group_all',1);
        })
        ->whereIn('allegato_id',$all_attachments_ids)
->orderBy('scadenza','DESC')
->groupBy('gruppo_cors','id_tipologia_grouped');;
```

Answer (score 0):

In Laravеl, whеn you create thе groupBy and ordеrBy clausеs togеthеr, you unеcncountеr unеcpеctеd rеsults bеcausе thе groupBy clausе usually distributes thе rеsults based on thе spеcifiеd column(s) and shifts thе first row in each group. This behavior could lead to thе "first id" issue you are seeing.

If you want to rеtriеvе thе rеcеnt documеnt in еach group, you can first detеrminе the latest scadеnza value for еach group and then use thе rеsult with your main query. Hеrе how you can modify your question to achiеvе this:

```php
$latestScadenzaQuery = Allegato::select('gruppo_cors', DB::raw('MAX(scadenza) as latest_scadenza'))
    ->groupBy('gruppo_cors');

$latestAttachments = Allegato::leftJoin('tsys_corsi', 'tsys_corsi.id_auto', 'allegati_files.tipo')
    ->joinSub($latestScadenzaQuery, 'latest_scadenza_query', function ($join) {
        $join->on('allegati_files.gruppo_cors', '=', 'latest_scadenza_query.gruppo_cors');
        $join->on('allegati_files.scadenza', '=', 'latest_scadenza_query.latest_scadenza');
    })
    ->get();
```

here is a more complex conditional grouping:

```php
    $attachments = DB:: table(DB:: raw('(
            SELECT allegati_files.*,
        IF(gruppo_cors IS NOT NULL, gruppo_cors, another_field) AS group_field
            FROM allegati_files
            LEFT JOIN tsys_corsi ON tsys_corsi.id_auto = allegati_files.tipo
            ORDER BY scadenza DESC
    ) AS temp_table'))
    -> groupBy('group_field')
    -> get();
```

Comment: Thank you but I can't use your example because my query is more complex. I have to groupBy gruppo_cors only if this field is not null otherwise i have to groupby another field otherwise not group by...

Comment: Any other suggestion?

Comment: you can use a subquery with DB::raw to pick out the fields you want from allegati_files. you can conditionally choose both gruppo_cors or another_field based on whether gruppo_cors isn't always null.

then you can perform the left be a part of and ordering within the subquery.

Then, you can alias this subquery as temp_table and pick from it within the main question.

you use groupBy at the group_field, which incorporates the conditional grouping subject.